# Android SDK VS Facebook R class conflict?

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-2.2-froyo

Okay first of all what I am doing is trying to integrate my Android game which is fully functional and tested to be working code onto Facebook. 
I have been following the Facebook tutorial on how to set it up for Facebook and have been using the Android SDK version of the support v4 file.
The problem I have been having seems to be a conflict between the two SDK's.

**R cannot be resolved to a variable.**

For example

```
MediaPlayer song = MediaPlayer.create(this.getContext(), R.raw.ironman);
```

**R.raw.ironman** is where the problem occurs, which is a reference to the raw folder in my resources directory, where the mp3 file ironman is found.
It uses the R class which is part of the Android SDK 
I had my game setup this way and it works great until I try to add the features from the tutorial.
For example

```
if (user != null) 
{
   TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
   welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
}
```

**R.id.welcome**
This uses the R class which is part of the Facebook SDK for accessing a control the way it looks.

Another thing I noticed was that it keeps deleting my Java files as well. 
from what I have read on other posts on here this is due to problems with the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.SmashEm"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/thumb"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:name="com.example.SmashEm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name=" com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Maybe I am going about this all wrong but I just thought I would give this a try.
Any help would be a appreciated and thanks.
Also I am pretty sure this is different then all the other threads I read so far but I could be wrong since I am not an expert in Java.

[image: Screenie1]

[image: Screenie2]

Comment: For the R problem control that you have imported the right R class.